# pg-promise number of updated rows

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I am using the pg-promise NodeJS module. At some point, I am updating one of my database's table. I would like to know how many rows have been updated by the query, is it possible?

Below is part of my code:

```
var queryText = "UPDATE public.mytable SET whatever = $1 WHERE criteria1=$2 AND criteria2=$3;",
    queryParam = [
      value1,
      value2,
      value3
    ];

    postgres.none(queryText, queryParam)
    .then((value) => {
      // how can I know at this point how many rows have been updated
      resolve(result);

    })
    .catch(err => {
      // it doesn't go here when zero row has been updated
      reject(err);
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). In order to access the advanced query-result details, you need to execute the query via method [result](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#result). And in your case you would access property `rowCount`:

```js
db.result(query, values, r => r.rowCount)
    .then(count => {
       // count = number of rows affected (updated or deleted) by the query
    })
    .catch(error => {
    });
```

P.S. You do not need to use `resolve(result)` inside `.then` or `reject(err)` inside `.catch`, as all query methods of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) already return promises.

**UPDATE**

Newer, ES7 syntax:

```js
const {rowCount} = await db.result(query, values);
```

Comment: If you're in an `async` function, you can also do e.g. `let result = await db.result('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE criteria1 = $1', ['foo'])`

Comment: @DaveGray That is self-evident when one moves from ES6 to ES7 syntax. At least you could have used the example correctly, with the transformation `r => r.rowCount` argument, or the example won't work otherwise.

Comment: You're right, it's not an exact drop-in replacement without doing `let result = await db.result('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE criteria1 = $1', ['foo'], r => r.rowCount)` - apologies to OP; in my use case I wanted to see the entire result object. Thanks for the library, it has saved me lots of time!

Comment: Added ES7 example.

Comment: when used with insert on conflict do update, how do I find out how many rows it inserted vs updated?

Comment: @PirateApp You can't. Postgres can only report how many rows have been affected/modified, without any specifics.